# How to return query criteria in callback in MongooseJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm new to the MongooseJS and Node.js and I have the following question.  I have some code that processes  a number of email addresses.

Here is my code:

```
for ( var i = 0, emailsToProcessLength = emailsToProcess.length;
      i < emailsToProcessLength;
      i++ ){
        Casual.findOne({ email: emailsToProcess[ i ] })
            .populate( 'affiliatedEmployers' )
            .exec( function ( err, casualFound ){

            if ( casualFound ) {
                linkExistingCasualWithEmployer( employerFound, casualFound );
            } else {
                processNewCasual( req, employerFound, emailsToProcess[ i ] );
            }
        });
    }
```

The code works fine with the 'linkExistingCasualWithEmployer()' method because the 'casualFound' is returned and I can see the email address that was found.

However, in the 'processNewCasual()' method, how can I see which email address was used in the original findOne() method to Mongoose? (e.g. in the callback, can I access the search criteria that was used?)

I cannot rely on the 'i' index of the array because by the time the callback is invoked, the for loop has progressed and is showing the last index.

Is a flow control library the only way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to refactor the email processing into a separate function so that the email address can be captured as a parameter:

```
function processEmail(email) {
    Casual.findOne({ email: email })
        .populate( 'affiliatedEmployers' )
        .exec( function ( err, casualFound ){

        if ( casualFound ) {
            linkExistingCasualWithEmployer( employerFound, casualFound );
        } else {
            processNewCasual( req, employerFound, email );
        }
    });
}

for ( var i = 0, emailsToProcessLength = emailsToProcess.length;
      i < emailsToProcessLength;
      i++ ) {
        processEmail( emailsToProcess[ i ] );
    }
```